# eclipse: expected ';' before string constant

Tags: c++, eclipse

I just managed to set up c++ compiler in Eclipse IDE, but now after first successfully building and executing this "Hello World" example i ran into this error message after just changing to "puts". But if I undo all these changes, the error stays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main(){

 //cout<< "Hello World!!!" ; // prints Hello World!!!
 puts("Hello World!!!"); // prints Hello World!!!
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you do a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Woks for me. Please include all the information needed to reproduce the problem in the question. Most likely, you are just compiling the wrong file on accident.